# How to add digits in output

Tags: python, list, file, addition

I have a file which I'm reading using python. In this file, I'm selecting certain numbers which are displayed as a list in the output, I want to add these numbers. Here is the code I'm using:

```
with open ("C:/xampp/htdocs/Final/uploads/file.dist", 'r') as rf:
    g = [rf.replace(' ', '') for rf in rf]  
k=[]
for e in g[1::47]:
    r=(e[:12])
    s=(r[:2])
    i.append(s)
m= Counter(i)
for letter in m:
    t= m[letter]
    print(t)
```

This gives me output as follows:

```
80
80
80
80
```

I want to add these number so that the final output will be 320 (80+80+80+80). I've tried listing method, import math library, but none of them is giving me the required output. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `s += t` inside loop with `s` initialized to 0 and print `s` outside loop?

Comment: You seem to use `rf` as the same name for 3 distinct objects: The file object, the `list` resulting from the comprehension, and a temporary `str` within the comprehension. It might work, but it's super confusing.

Comment: @Austin it gives 80 only 1 time. When I try printing it outside the loop, I get 80 as a result and that only once (not 4 times).

Comment: `+=`, not just `=`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that only, s += t

Comment: Edit your question to include that.

Comment: Please post **all the code that you're running**. For example, `i.append(s)` wouldn't work. So the code you posted can;t have that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use += instead of = to add the values of m[letter] to t:

```
from collections import Counter
with open ("C:/path/file.dist", 'r') as rf:
    g = [rf.replace(' ', '') for rf in rf]
i=[]
for e in g[1::47]:
    r=(e[:12])
    s=(r[:2])
    i.append(s)

m = Counter(i)
t = 0
for letter in m:
    t += m[letter]
print(t)
```

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: @Dustrokes Can you share the file please (file.dist)?

Comment: I've added the hyperlink to the file, you'll have to download the file, since its not available to preview.

Comment: @Dustrokes, I editied the code above. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Dustrokes, If this works, I urge you to go through my first comment on your question; was literally talking the same.